# JSON / PHP : Json_encode with [ ]

Tags: php, json

I would like to write this request in PHP, but I don't know how to translate [,] in my PHP request :

JSON :

```
{
    "output": "extend",
    "filter": {
        "host": [
            "Zabbix server",
            "Linux server"
        ]
    }
}
```

PHP :

```
array(
    'output' => 'extend',
    'filter' => array (
        'host' => ???
            "Zabbix server",
            "Linux server"
        ???
    )
)
```

Can you please help me ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinwent the wheel. Use `json_decode()` to do the job: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I just want to immediately write the PHP expression ! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Then you basically shall rephrase your question as it is not clear what you really want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'output' => 'extend',
    'filter' => array (
        host => array(
            "Zabbix server",
            "Linux server"
        )
    )
)
```

You can use `$arry   =  json_decode($json_string,true);` which will give you array as output

Comment: So, {} and [] are translated with 'array( )' ? How is it possible to reencode this ?

Comment: {} - object, and [] - for array